# Assign values to object with different property types by dynamic indexing

Tags: typescript

My aim is to update one object dynamically using a different object of the same type.

The object has properties of differing types:

```
type TypeOne = 'good' | 'okay';
type TypeTwo = 'default' | 'one';

interface Option {
  year: TypeOne,
  date?: TypeTwo
}

const currentData:Option = {
  year: 'good',
  date: 'default'
}
```

Here is the other object used to update `currentData`:

```
const newData:Option = {
  year: 'okay',
}
```

I have an array used to index the object dynamically:

```
const params: (keyof typeof currentData)[] = ['year', 'date'];
```

Here is the update procedure where the issue appears:

```
params.forEach((param) => {

  currentData[param] = newData[param]  //  error: currentData[param] is inferred as type 'never' 
  
  if(param === 'year'){                 // if I would typecheck param, there would be no error
    currentData[param] = newData[param]    // But then it won't be dynamic anymore 
  }
  
});
```

It doesn't matter if I typecheck if `param` is in `currentData` since param is already `keyof typeof currentData`.

I can check the parameter literally, but then it's not dynamic anymore.

I believe that the problem is that `currentData[param]` is inferred as all the possible values, but when assigning a new value, it doesn't know which type it belongs to.

But I think all it needs to know is that currentData and newData is of the same type and that both are "in sync" since the same parameter is used to index both when assigning the value. So it theoretically has enough info.

So is there a way to make typescript see that the objects are "synced"?

Comment: Or just get around using a loop and use `Object.assign(currentData, newData)`.

Comment: This function cannot be typesafe, but you can make a typesafe wrapper out of this function, or cast `Object.assign` to a typesafe wrapper

Comment: The recommended approach here is to use generics as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NnLQ6W). See [ms/TS#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693) and the SO questions/answers linked above for more information.

Comment: @jcalz thanks, that solution works fantastically.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with your current setup: Use a type assertion to assure TypeScript that `currentData[param]` is of type `Option[param]`.

```
params.forEach((param) => {
  (currentData[param] as Option[typeof param]) = newData[param];  // works :)
});
```

Also, if you're going to do things this way, you should strengthen the type of your `params` array so that errors will show up if the target objects don't match types. As it is now, if `newData` isn't of type `Option`, your `forEach()` won't complain, which is bad. You could achieve this by intersecting the keys of the target objects, for example, but you can decide what the most reasonable approach is.

```
const params: (keyof typeof currentData & keyof typeof newData)[] = ['year', 'date']; // no error
const params: (keyof typeof currentData & keyof {random: 3})[] = ['year', 'date']; // error
```